# Profile page shows tags and post count for deleted posts

Tags: bug, profile-page, deleted-questions

[A user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5338998/nsk-eblog?tab=profile) had some posts deleted earlier (about an hour and 20 minutes ago). I went back to the profile later and found this:

[image]

Why does the tag section show the tags the user has participated in if there are no un-deleted posts? Are these stats supposed to show deleted posts?

The user also has 0 (public) actions.

Comment: It might be that the tag information only updates when the tag score script runs.

Comment: Blame caching[?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: That's a big problem with the caching system if dynamic content is not being re cached that's the most difficult & main part of setting up caching  and should not be used as an excuse it's a bug that need fixing then...

Comment: The various places that you can see your total score in a tag are erratic too. Check badge progress, profile tab and then the tags tab in activity. Or hm. They're normally erratic but actually match up for me right now.

Comment: @Kyll i saw your link at my work and i laughed so hard that my supervisor summed me. :-D

Answer (score 2):

The tag information is gone from the profile now. Best bet is that we needed to wait for a recalculation as [Nathan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311456/profile-page-shows-tags-and-post-count-for-deleted-posts#comment277685_311456) says.

> It might be that the tag information only updates when the tag score script runs.